# How to identify if the current site is a subsite or site-collection from UI

Tags: site-collection, sub-site

Assuming that I have the admin access for the current site, how do I identify if the current site is a subsite or a site collection?

Comment: You want to identify this from code or from UI?

Comment: @BijuJoseph-MCSD From UI

Comment: From URL itself we can easily identify or below given explanation is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the gear symbol and select the site settings from the drop down.

[image: Site Settings]

If you see the `Site Collection Administration` groups with all relevant links as in the image below then it means you are on a site collection.
[image: Site Collection Settings.]

If you see the `Site Collection Administration` with a single link saying `Go to top level site settings` as in the image below then you are on subsite.
[image]